Pacemaker stalls on failing resources and does not start other resources that could be started
I am setting up 3 hosts exporting their own drive via iscsi, and using pacemaker to manage which of the 3 hosts assemble them into a unique raid 5 ZFS device. The whole setup is structured as follows:
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|>----- host1-host3 ------------------------|
|                                                                         |                                           |
|                                               [require-all=false]       |                                           |
|                                                             |           |                                           |
| target-host1 - lun-host1 -|-|-- iscsi-host1-direct-clone ---|           |                                           |
|                           | |>- iscsi-host1-indirect-clone -|- host1 -|-|---------------------|>--- host1-host2 ----|
|                           |>--- iscsi-host1-sync-clone -----|         |                       |                     |
|                                                                       |                       |                     |
| |--------------------------------------------------------------------<|                       |                     |
| |                                                                                             |                     |
| |                                               [require-all=false]                           |                     |
| |                                                             |                               |                     |
| | target-host2 - lun-host2 -|-|-- iscsi-host2-direct-clone ---|                               |                     |-raid
| |                           | |>- iscsi-host2-indirect-clone -|- host2 -----|-----------------|----|                |
| |                           |>--- iscsi-host2-sync-clone -----|             |                      |                |
| |                                                                           |                      |                |
| |---------------------------------------------------------------------|>----|>- host1-host2-host3 ------------------|
|                                                                       |                            |                |
|                                               [require-all=false]     |                            |                |
|                                                             |         |                            |                |
| target-host3 - lun-host3 -|-|-- iscsi-host3-direct-clone ---|         |                            |                |
|                           | |>- iscsi-host3-indirect-clone -|- host3 -|-|--------------------------|>- host2-host3 -| 
|                           |>--- iscsi-host3-sync-clone -----|           |                                           |
|                                                                         |                             [require-all=false]
|------------------------------------------------------------------------<|

Where each link between resource is a order constraint (I added a > to make the link's direction explicit where I thought it was ambiguous). Colocation constraints are not represented.
The problem I have is that resources iscsi-host[1,2,3]-[direct,indirect] rely on some network that... tend to crash for reasons I can't figure out (my question about this issue on superuser) but that I'd like to keep because of the nice bandwidth bump is should provide me. iscsi-host[1,2,3]-sync-clone rely on a very classic bridge with STP enabled and has been working flawlessly. I setup resources iscsi-host[1,2,3]-[direct,indirect,sync] with meta property failure-timeout=20 and resource raid with meta failure-timeout=20 so that if they fail, pacemaker tries again after a while to start these resources again, without having to intervene manually.
The problem I have is that when I move resource raid from one host to another while resources iscsi-host[1,2,3]-[direct,indirect] are failed, pacemaker is focused on restoring resources iscsi-host[1,2,3]-[direct,indirect] first and does not actually care about moving raid or other resources it depends on, and thus any failover operation while the direct and indirect variants of iscsi just stalls forever. I tried to set higher priorities to resources depending on how close they are to the final resource (resource raid has the highest priority, resources host1-host2 and siblings have a slightly lower priority and so on), but then when pacemaker is determined to start raid before it starts any of the host1-host2 and siblings and so on recursively, also resulting in resource raid never being started. What I would like is that once any of the iscsi-hostX-[direct,indirect,sync]-clone resources manage to get started for a given X, then pacemaker proceeds to start resources further in the graph, and only cares about the remaining iscsi-hostX-[direct,indirect,sync]-clone once resource raid has been started. Can any pacemaker wizard get me in the right direction?

I believe the root of the problem described has to do with the colocation constraints I chose to not represent in the question. Basically, a non-running colocated resource will prevent any other resource to run, even if all its order constraints are fulfilled. I asked for help for this specific question on Server fault (where this question might have been better to begin with), as well as a solution for it that I still wish could be improved.
